# Getting a, “The file specified is not a virtual disk. Cannot open the disk xxxx or one of the snapshot disks it depends on” in Vmware Workstation

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

I am running Windows 10 using VMware Workstation 16 on my Window 10 Laptop. All was well until I put my VM into suspended mode and then put my computer to sleep for the night. Once I booted it up it gave me an error saying that it couldn't find the virtual disk (sorry I don't have the exact error message). So, I provided it a VMDK file from yesterday. Now I am getting this error.

```
The file specified is not a virtual disk

Cannot open the disk 'C:\Users\[user]\Documents\Virtual Machines\Windows 1809 - Box\Windows 1809 - Box-000005-s015.vmdk' or one of the snapshot disks it depends on.

Module 'Disk' power on failed.

Failed to start the virtual machine.
```

I must've given it the wrong vmdk file. But when I go to Settings, it is not letting change the file path to a different vmdk.

VMWare VM settings:

[image: VMWare VM settings]

[image]

[image]

I have two questions:

1. Why did the VM loose track of the VMDK disk when I put it into suspended mode?
2. How can I give VMware the correct VMDK so that the VM will boot up again?

Comment: You can upload images and provide links to that image regardless of your reputation.  You just can't inline the screenshot.  Asking for reputation or upvotes is frowned upon.  However, `Windows 1809 - Box-000005-s015.vmdk` is listed in the configuration file for the VM, but snapshots are incremental so if you attempt to rollback to a previous snapshot it will either work and you will be missing your changes or it simply won't work.  If the .vmdk file is missing then you will be unable to boot the VM. (I can't tell if that is a snapshot or not).

Comment: Alright. Sorry about that. I will upload a couple screenshots

Comment: Look in the folder for the machine and make sure you are starting from the VMX file which VMware uses to start and then from there loads the VMDK main file.

Comment: @John It appears to be loading the VMX correctly. But whenever I try to resume the suspended virtual machine, I get the same error. I updated the original post with a picture of the error dialog.

Comment: One thing I have done is to create a new machine (so new VMX) file of the same kind as the non starting machine. This is in a new folder. COPY the VMDK file from its folder to the new folder and see if the machine starts now. Also follow this VMware article for recovering a machine with an uncombined snapshot:  https://communities.vmware.com/t5/ESXi-Discussions/Recover-Snapshoted-VMDK-file/td-p/2209273

Comment: @John, I am looking at the community discussion you linked me to. I'm not sure how to solve my problem because I don't see a normal vmdk file. All I see are snapshots ect...What should I do? (I added a picture of my VM directory)

Comment: The only vmdk files that I have are ones with '-sxxx' in them

Comment: I think all you have are snapshot files and I do not think (and cannot find anything) that you can re-create a VMDK file (basic machine file) from snapshots. I think you will need to create a new machine.

Comment: "I provided it a VMDK file from yesterday." Where did that VMDK file come from?  Is it from a backup of the entire VM?  Also, you should be able to find the exact, original error message from the one of the `.log` files in the VM's directory.

Comment: @John The .`vmdk` naming format is `NAME-SNAPSHOT-sEXTENT.vmdk`, so `s####` indicates the disk extent for split disks.  That there appear to be files named just `NAME-sEXTENT` indicates that (at least some of) the original base disk files should still be present.

Comment: @john, the vmdk wile that I provided it with yesterday was a snapshot file. I ended up having to just recreate my vm from scratch unfortunately. Thanks a lot for all the help