# Vmware Workstation - The file specified is not a virtual disk. Cannot open the disk xxxx or one of the snapshot disks it depends on

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I am running Windows 10 using VMware Workstation 16 on my Window 10 Laptop. All was well until I put my VM into suspended mode and then put my computer to sleep for the night. Once I booted it up it gave me an error saying that it couldn't find the virtual disk (sorry I don't have the exact error message). So, I provided it a VMDK file from yesterday. Now I am getting this error.

```
The file specified is not a virtual disk

Cannot open the disk 'C:\Users\[user]\Documents\Virtual Machines\Windows 1809 - Box\Windows 1809 - Box-000005-s015.vmdk' or one of the snapshot disks it depends on.

Module 'Disk' power on failed.

Failed to start the virtual machine.
```

I must've given it the wrong vmdk file. But when I go to Settings, it is not letting change the file path to a different vmdk.

[image]

I have two questions:

1. Why did the VM loose track of the VMDK disk when I put it into suspended mode?
2. How can I give VMware the correct VMDK so that the VM will boot up again?

Comment: This is a double-post of https://superuser.com/q/1665209/.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a stale lock on that file.

Right click on the virtual machine, then go to Open VM directory. If you find any .lck file with the same name as your virtual machine, delete it and restart the VM.

EDIT

Failing that, your vmdk may indeed be corrupted for some reason.

If this is the case, you may revert to a snapshot (if available).

If you don't have a snapshot, you can try to inspect the .vmdk file, or maybe a copy, with 7-zip (right click on the file -> Open archive), save the files you want to keep and then rebuilding the VM with the right image and settings. After you re-install the OS, copy the old files and you should be (relatively) fine.

Comment: I don't see any more .lck files in the directory.

Comment: There is only a cache dir, some log files, a bunch of vmdk files, a nvram, a vmsd, a vmx, a vmxf, a vmem, and a vmss in the directory.

Comment: @barley is there some .lck file in a subdirectory?

Comment: No, there aren't. It seems that the error that I put in my original post says that the vmdk file that I selected as my "Disk file" is incorrect...

Comment: @barley edited my answer. your vmdk file may indeed be corrupted, which means you would have to revert to snapshots or rebuild the VM.

Comment: I do have a snapshot. But for some reason the option to revert to it is greyed out.

Comment: Would there be any harm in just deleting the vmss file? This would probably loose some imediate state but might allow me to get back to a recent state?

Comment: @barley there shouldn't be any harm, but I've never done it myself. You may want to copy the vmss file somewhere else first, if you want to be on the safe side.

Comment: Well, that didn't work. Still the same issue

Comment: I ended up just having to create an entire new VM. The base VMDK file that the VM is based off of was gone, leaving no viable way to redeem this vm. Therefore, I had to create a new one.